# How to fix "Constructor not defined:<Constructor>()" error when calling constructor method with no parameters?

Tags: apex

```
public class ABCMembersRecurringBatch extends ABCClubSyncBatchInterface{
    public Map<String,String> planMap = new Map<String,String>();

    public static void run(){
        ABCMembersRecurringBatch b = new ABCMembersRecurringBatch([SELECT id, ClubNo__c FROM Club__c WHERE isAuthorized__c = TRUE AND ClubNo__c != NULL], System.today().addDays(-565), System.today(), 180,  '/members/recurringservices?saleTimestampRange=',ABCFinancialsParser.MemberRecuringResponse.class, 100);

        Database.executeBatch(b, 1);
    }

    public ABCMembersRecurringBatch(List<Club__c> clubs, Date startDate, Date endDate, Integer range, String endpoint, Type responseType, Integer minBatch){

        super(clubs, startDate, endDate, range, endpoint, responseType, minBatch);
    }

    @TestVisible
    public override void toSObject(List<ABCFinancialsParser.APIResponse> qrs){
        List<Recurring_Service__c> services = new List<Recurring_Service__c>();

        for(ABCFinancialsParser.APIResponse q : qrs){
            String endpointPlan = '/' + q.club.ClubNo__c + '/clubs/recurringserviceplans';
            ABCFinancialsParser.RecurringPlanResponse plans = (ABCFinancialsParser.RecurringPlanResponse)JSON.deserialize(ABCFinancialsAPI.doGet(endpointPlan), ABCFinancialsParser.RecurringPlanResponse.class);
            for(ABCFinancialsParser.RecurringServicePlan plan : plans.recurringServicePlans){
                planMap.put(plan.recurringServicePlanId, plan.recurringServicePlanName);
            }
            ABCFinancialsParser.MemberRecuringResponse m = (ABCFinancialsParser.MemberRecuringResponse)q;
            if(m != NULL && m.recurringServices != NULL){
                for(ABCFinancialsParser.RecurringService rs : m.recurringServices){
                    Recurring_Service__c service = new Recurring_Service__c(
                        Club__c =  q.club.Id,
                        Agreement_No__c = rs.agreementNumber,
                        Auto_Renew__c = rs.autoRenew,
                        Billed__c =  Decimal.valueOf(rs.numberBilled),
                        Campaign_Name__c = rs.campaignName,
                        Contact__r = new Contact(
                            DataTrackID__c = rs.memberId
                        ),
                        Agreement__r = new Agreement__c(
                            External_Id__c = rs.agreementNumber + '||' + rs.memberId
                        ),
                        Recurring_Service_Plan__c = planMap.get(rs.recurringServicePlanId),
                        First_Billing_Date__c = Date.valueOf(rs.recurringServiceDates.firstBillingDate),
                        Frequency__c = rs.frequency,
                        Recurring_Service_Id__c = rs.recurringServiceId,
                        Recurring_Service_Plan_Id__c = rs.recurringServicePlanId,
                        Reorder_Quantity__c = Decimal.valueOf(rs.reorderQuantity),
                        Sale_Date__c = Date.valueOf(rs.recurringServiceDates.saleDate),
                        Service_Item__c = rs.serviceItem,
                        Status__c = rs.recurringServiceStatus,
                        Total_Invoice__c = Decimal.valueOf(rs.invoiceTotal),
                        Total_Periods__c = rs.totalPeriods,
                        Type__c = rs.recurringTypeDesc,
                        Unit_Price__c = Decimal.valueOf(rs.unitPrice)
                    );
                    if(rs.recurringServiceDates.nextBillingDate <> NULL){
                        service.Next_Billing_Date__c = Date.valueOf(rs.recurringServiceDates.nextBillingDate);
                    }
                    if(rs.recurringServiceDates.finalBillingDate <> NULL){
                        service.Final_Billing_Date__c = Date.valueOf(rs.recurringServiceDates.finalBillingDate);
                    }
                    if(rs.recurringServiceDates.inactiveDate <> NULL){
                        service.Inactive_Date__c = Date.valueOf(rs.recurringServiceDates.inactiveDate);
                    }
                    if(rs.recurringServiceDates.startFreezeDate <> NULL){
                        service.Start_Freeze_Date__c = Date.valueOf(rs.recurringServiceDates.startFreezeDate);
                    }
                    if(rs.recurringServiceDates.endFreezeDate <> NULL){
                        service.End_Freeze_Date__c = Date.valueOf(rs.recurringServiceDates.endFreezeDate);
                    }
                    if(rs.recurringServiceDates.deactivateReason <> NULL){
                        service.Deactivate_Reason__c = rs.recurringServiceDates.deactivateReason;
                    }
                    if(rs.commissionsEmployeeIds <> NULL){
                        service.Commissions_Employee_Ids__c = String.join(rs.commissionsEmployeeIds, ',');
                    }
                    services.add(service);
                }
            }

        }
        List<Database.UpsertResult> res = Database.upsert(services, Recurring_Service__c.Recurring_Service_Id__c, false);
        insertLog('Recurring Service', services, res, 'Recurring_Service__c');
    }
}
```

-------Test class is----

```
@isTest
private Class ABCMembersRecurringBatchTest {
    static testMethod void testExecute(){
        Club__c cl = new Club__c(
            ClubNo__c = 'test123', 
            isAuthorized__c = true
        );
        insert cl;

        Test.startTest();
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.Class, new ABCClubAndMemberMock());
        ABCMembersRecurringBatch abc = new ABCMembersRecurringBatch();
        database.executeBatch(abc);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have any default constructor but parameterized constructor for the `ABCMembersRecurringBatch` class, you need to call that in the test class in the similar way you have done in run().

Answer (score 2):

The line in your test:

```
ABCMembersRecurringBatch abc = new ABCMembersRecurringBatch();
```

is assuming your batch has a default (no argument) constructor, but you have defined a constructor with arguments:

```
public ABCMembersRecurringBatch(List<Club__c> clubs, Date startDate, Date endDate, Integer range, String endpoint, Type responseType, Integer minBatch)
```

You should pass the relevant values to the construction in the test or add a default constructor to the batch as needed. (It would be better to add the passing of parameters to make sure the test exercises the code in the same way as it is used in production.)